# orWhere clause optimization

Tags: php, laravel

I have my block of code like this:

```
$articulos = Articulo::select('id', 'descripcion', 'status', 'codigo_interno', 'codigo_comercial', 'unidad_medida', 'impuestos_compra', 'validar_peso')
        ->where('descripcion','like', '%' . $palabra_buscar . '%')->where('status', 'activo')
        ->orWhere('codigo_interno','like', '%' . $palabra_buscar . '%')->where('status', 'activo')
        ->orWhere('codigo_comercial','like', '%' . $palabra_buscar . '%')->where('status', 'activo')
        ->get()
```

What I want is to improve this code by avoiding using a lot of **->where('status', 'activo')** statements.

I´m doing this because if I write ->where('status', 'activo') at the end of the query, the only statement that works is the last one. It seems that the orWhere clause resets the query.

Thank you.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses

Answer (score 1):

Did you try by using a closure?

```
$articulos = Articulo::select('id', 'descripcion', 'status', 'codigo_interno', 'codigo_comercial', 'unidad_medida', 'impuestos_compra', 'validar_peso')
    ->where('status', 'activo')
    ->where(function($query){
        $query
          ->orWhere('descripcion','like', '%' . $palabra_buscar . '%')
          ->orWhere('codigo_interno','like', '%' . $palabra_buscar . '%')
          ->orWhere('codigo_comercial','like', '%' . $palabra_buscar . '%');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Move the status outside of the enclosure, since that's an AND clause

Comment: Thanks @aynber I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

start by filtering by activo for query optmisation, by starting with it yu will next on the second where filter only on activo ariculos.(hope this make sens).

```
$articulos = Articulo::select('id', 'descripcion', 'status', 'codigo_interno', 'codigo_comercial', 'unidad_medida', 'impuestos_compra', 'validar_peso')
    ->where('status', 'activo')
    ->Where(function($query)use($palabra_buscar) {
            $query->where('descripcion','like', '%' . $palabra_buscar . '%')
    ->orWhere('codigo_interno','like', '%' . $palabra_buscar . '%')
    ->orWhere('codigo_comercial','like', '%' . $palabra_buscar . '%');
        })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score -3):

please try this

```
$articulos = Articulo::select('id', 'descripcion', 'status', 'codigo_interno', 'codigo_comercial', 'unidad_medida', 'impuestos_compra', 'validar_peso')
        ->where('descripcion','like', '%' . $palabra_buscar . '%')
        ->orWhere('codigo_interno','like', '%' . $palabra_buscar . '%')
        ->orWhere('codigo_comercial','like', '%' . $palabra_buscar . '%')
         ->where('status', 'activo')
        ->get()
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP said that didn't work: `I´m doing this because if I write ->where('status', 'activo') at the end of the query, the only statement that works is the last one`